# Smooth numbers in short intervals

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Let $\psi(x,y)$ be the number of positive integers up to $x$ which are $y$-smooth, that is, integers whose prime factors are at most of size $y$. There has been, for a few decades now, a lot of activity around $\psi$, and in particular, it has been studied in short intervals and in arithmetic progressions.

> Question: Consider the difference $$\psi(x+x^{\beta},x^{\alpha}) -\psi(x,x^{\alpha})$$ for fixed $1>\alpha,\beta>0$. When is it
>   asymptotic to  $$x^{\beta} \frac{\psi(x,x^{\alpha})}{x}?$$

This is addressed in Section 4 of [a thorough survey](http://math.utoledo.edu/~codenth/Spring_13/3200/NT-books/Smooth_Numbers-Computational_Number_Theory_and_Beyond-Granville.pdf) by Granville from 2008. Hildebrand proved that these two quantities are asymptotic when $\beta \ge 1-\frac{5}{12} \alpha$, and apparently this can be improved, without introducing new ideas, to
$$\beta > 1-\alpha.$$
Moreover, in a paper by Friedland and Granville they prove an asymptotic result for $$\beta> \frac{1}{2}+2\alpha.$$

My question is, has there been any progress on the (asymptotic) question above since the results just stated, even conditionally on the Riemann Hypothesis? In particular, is the asymptotic result known, conditionally or not, when
$$\beta > \frac{1}{2},$$
with no restrictions on $\alpha$?

Reading the various recent works on the subject, it is not clear to me if this is known or not.

Comment: Existence is given by Matomaki-Radziwill in https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.04585